# CSS - Applying Transitions

Tags: html, css

I'm not new to CSS but for some reason I've not played with animations or transitions up to this point. I want to learn how to apply any form of transition to a tooltip that I've made, but every time I read code and then try I seem to fail. I have a quick example of code I put together and maybe someone can quickly show me what I'm doing wrong.

Note: This is only an example, I don't plan to use a 2 second transition, makes it clear that it's working.

Following is the key code, please see the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/52z9R/).

```
label[data-tooltip] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover:after {
        transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
        .borderRadius(3px);
        content: attr(data-tooltip);
        background: rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.95);
        text-transform: none;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 13px;
        width: 100px;
        z-index: 99;
        color: #fff;
        bottom: 120%;
        left: -5px;
    }

    &:after {
        display: none;
    }

    &:hover:after {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is LESS syntax, won't work with general CSS

Comment: Please elaborate for how this affects using transitions? Sorry that statement is so broad it sounds like you mean using LESS won't work with CSS, which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/gsgQf/1/)

you should assign all the styles to the after
and to the hover status just the attribute you want to animate

```
label[data-tooltip] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:after {
        transition: all ease  5s;
        content: attr(data-tooltip);
        background: rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.95);
        text-transform: none;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 13px;
        width: 100px;
        z-index: 99;
        color: #fff;
        bottom: 120%;
        left: -5px;   
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &:hover:after {
        opacity: 1;

    }
}

.formRow {
    background: #EFEFEF;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
.formRow-label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.formRow-input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, right on the money. Really helping me see what was missing.